# How do I disable this code view setting in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I don't know whats combination of keys I performed, but now my code looks like this, with a bunch of dots!

[image: Code with Dots!]

How do I disable this? Been looking for some time and can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this shortcut will do it : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>

Or the slow way : Edit -> Advanced -> and uncheck "View Whitespace"

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>. This toggles the dots.

Comment: Ctrl+E, Ctrl+S will only work if you are using the C# Keyboard mappings

Comment: DIdn't know that about C# mapping only. Either way, it is `Edit->Advanced Ooptions->View White Space`

Answer (score 0):

- Edit
- Advanced Options
- View White Space